# Alternate sum of Worpitzky numbers (similar to Stirling numbers)

Tags: combinatorics

Considering the [Worpitzky numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Connection_with_Worpitzky_numbers) $W(n, k)$, defined in terms of the [Stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) of the second kind $S(n, k)$ as
$$
W(n, k) = k!S(n, k) = \sum_{i=0}^k (-)^i \binom{k}{i} (k-i)^n
$$

**Begin Edit**

It is the wrong definition for the Worpitzky numbers (see comments), sorry for that (it was late). The real definition is 
$$
W(n, k) = k!S(n+1, k+1)
$$
I do not change the rest of the question to not be confusing with respect to the answers.

**End Edit**

I suspect the alternate sum of $W(n, k)$ for fixed $n$ (number of elements in the set) is given by
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n(-)^kW(n, k) = (-)^n
$$

This question is a follow up to my [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/459072/identification-of-special-numbers-based-on-recursive-formula-combinatorics) on the subject. In that context, I could verify

$$
\sum_{k=1}^1(-)^kW(1, k) = -1
$$

$$
\sum_{k=1}^2 (-)^k W(2, k) = -1 + 2 = 1
$$

$$
\sum_{k=1}^3 (-)^k W(3, k) = -1 + 6 - 6 = -1
$$

$$
\sum_{k=1}^4 (-)^k W(4, k) = -1 + 14 - 36 + 24 = 1
$$

But I can't find anything in my brain or googlable literature to generalize this.

Comment: Your definition for the Worpitzky numbers is a little off: $W(n,k) = k! S(n+1,k+1)$ not $k! S(n,k)$.  Your claim may still be true, but it's about other numbers.  Your numbers appear in the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequence as [A019538](http://oeis.org/A019538).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative to Marko's answer that doesn't use exponential generating functions.  As implied in his answer and my comment, your question is not about the Worpitzky numbers $k! S(n+1,k+1)$ (using your notation for the Stirling numbers of the second kind) rather the numbers $k! S(n,k)$ which are [A019538](http://oeis.org/A019538).  As a triangle $T(n,k)$ for $1 \le k\le n$, they begin
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 6 & 6 \\ 1 & 14 & 36 & 24 \\ 1 & 30 & 150 & 240 & 120
\end{array}
Note the relation row to row is similar to Pascal's triangle but weighted by column: $$T(n,k) = k\left(T(n-1,k-1)+T(n-1,k)\right).$$  That's enough to prove your alternating sum identity using induction.  For instance, for the fourth row,
\begin{align}
-T(4,1)&+T(4,2)-T(4,3)+T(4,4) \\
& = -1 + 2(T(3,1)+T(3,2)) - 3(T(3,2)+T(3,3))+4(T(3,3)+T(3,4)) \\
& = -1 + T(3,1) + [T(3,1)-T(3,2)+T(3,3)] \\
& = -1 + 1 - [-T(3,1)+T(3,2)-T(3,3)] \\
& = 0 -(-1) \\
& = 1
\end{align}
where the bracketed expression in the third to last line is the alternating third row sum.

Comment: Thanks! I looked at this yesterday but was to tired to see the term reassignment in the series after applying the triangular rule. Maybe for future readers you could add it explicitly in general terms to your answer.

Comment: $n T(n-1, n) + T(n-1, 0) + \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} (-)^k \left( -(k+1) T(k,n-1) + k T(k,n-1) \right)$ with $T(n-1, n) = T(n-1, 0)  = 0$

Comment: $(-)^n$ for the first term, not that it matters.

Comment: @Wilmerton  Thanks.  I'm curious about using $(-)^k$ for $(-1)^k$, I haven't seen that before.

Comment: Ho, I don't remember where it comes from. I studied theoretical physics - those guys like shorthand notations.

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition by [Wikipedia 
I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Connection_with_Worpitzky_numbers) and [Wikipedia 
II](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principe_d%27inclusion-exclusion#Nombres_de_Worpitzky) we have

$$W_{n,k} = k! {n+1\brace k+1}.$$

This gives for the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k W_{n,k} =
\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k k! {n+1\brace k+1} =
-1 + \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k k! {n+1\brace k+1}
\\ = -1 + \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k k! (n+1)! [z^{n+1}]
\frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}
\\ = -1 + n! [z^{n}]
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k k!
\frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!} \exp(z)
\\ = -1 + n! [z^{n}] \exp(z)
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k (\exp(z)-1)^k
\\ = -1 + n! [z^{n}] \exp(z)
\sum_{k=0}^n (1-\exp(z))^k
\\ = -1 + n! [z^{n}] \exp(z)
\frac{1-(1-\exp(z))^{n+1}}{1-(1-\exp(z))}
\\ = -1 + n! [z^{n}]
(1-(1-\exp(z))^{n+1}).$$

Now since $1-\exp(z) = -z - \cdots$ we have $[z^n] (1-\exp(z))^{n+1} =
0$ so that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k W_{n,k} = -1.$$

If on the other hand we are working with the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k k!  {n\brace k}$$

we obtain

$$n! [z^n] \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k (\exp(z)-1)^k$$

which is for $n\ge 1$

$$n! [z^n] \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k (\exp(z)-1)^k
= n! [z^n] \sum_{k=0}^n (1-\exp(z))^k
\\ = n! [z^n] \exp(-z) (1-(1-\exp(z))^{n+1})
= n! [z^n] \exp(-z) = (-1)^n.$$

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I know it is the first, but it is arguably more complicated than @Brian Hopkins answer to include in a non-mathematical document.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach: Denote $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$. We have for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$,

$$
x^n=\sum_{k=0}^n S(n,k) (x)_k
$$
where $(x)_k=x(x-1)\cdots (x-k+1)$ is the falling factorial.

*Proof*. It suffices to prove the identity for all natural number $x$. The LHS is the number of $x$-colorings of $[n]$. The summand in the RHS,
$$
S(n,k) k!\binom xk, 
$$
is the number of ways to select $k$ colors from $x$ colors and color $[n]$ using all selected colors.

Proof of the alternating sum identity:

Put $x=-1$ into the identity, we have
$$
(-1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^nS(n,k)k! (-1)^k.  
$$

For Worpitzky numbers $W(n,k)=S(n+1,k+1)k!$, we modify the identity by $k\binom xk = x \binom{x-1}{k-1}$. We have
$$
x^n=\sum_{k=1}^nS(n,k)(k-1)!x\binom{x-1}{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}S(n,k+1)k!x\binom{x-1}k.
$$
Replacing $n$ by $n+1$, we have
$$
x^{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^nS(n+1,k+1)k!x\binom{x-1}k.
$$
We drop $x$ and replace $x$ by $x+1$, we have
$$
(x+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^nS(n+1,k+1)k!\binom xk.
$$
Put $x=-1$ above, then
$$
0=\sum_{k=0}^nS(n+1,k+1)k!(-1)^k.
$$
Isolating $k=0$ in the summation, we obtain the alternating sum identity for Worpitzky numbers.